# blank/white Screen not being rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting a blank screen in react app after running it with npm start
it worked adequately till yesterday but now it is getting this error and I don't think the code is getting rendered because when I checked the inspect window to enable javascript

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "buildfolks",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
  },
  "main": "postcss.config.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

App.js

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Nav from './Nav.js';

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "BuildFolks";
  });
}

<Nav />

export default App;
```

I am also using tailwind css

Comment: Did you check for errors in your web browser console? A blank screen is usually [an error in render](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#new-behavior-for-uncaught-errors).

Comment: Yes There is none

Comment: add sample in codesandbox is better for debug

Comment: Your `App()` function does not return anything.

Comment: how can i fix it

Comment: but there i am rendering nav component

Answer (score 4):

Your `App()` function does not return anything, try to make it return `<Nav />`:

```js
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "BuildFolks";
  });
  return <Nav />;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your App component is missing the `return` statement.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Nav from './Nav.js';

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
   document.title = "BuildFolks";
  });

 return (
    <Nav />
  )

}

export default App;
```